# Using GUI functionality on an event (MVVM)

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I recently started developing with Xamarin and MVVM and I came across a problem, I don't really know how to solve.

I bound my events in the `View` to `ICommand` properties in my `ViewModel`. But these events should be able to trigger for example a `DisplayAlert` or a `Navigation.PushAsync` call.

Now I know there are some workarounds for these problems, but wouldn't reference a `Navigation` object in the `ViewModel` violate against the intended use of a `ViewModel`, that it doesn't know anything of the `View`?

I would really like to maintain a strict, pure MVVM pattern, so how can I achieve this?

**Edit**

Thanks for your answers. I've searched a bit more and found some libraries for `Xamarin.forms` that were mentioned in [this](https://xamarinhelp.com/navigating-xamarin-forms/) blog post, which seem to help.

I will try out [prism](http://prismlibrary.github.io/index.html), which has a `Navigation Service` and a `Page Dialog Service`.

**Edit 02**

Otherwise, you could use the [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) as @Julien mentioned.

Comment: Hi, I think this link will be usefull: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120090/who-should-control-navigation-in-an-mvvm-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EvZ answer is good. **You have to check common MVVM practices**...

In anyway, if you really don't want to use these patterns, **you could use events** (sometimes, in some scenarii, it can be useful..). Look at the sample code below (The code is simple but you can factorize UI 'functions' over pages, make it cleaner...)

Instead of events, **you could also use Xamarin MessagingCenter** to connect your View to its ViewModel (ref: [Xamarin MessagingCenter documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

ie:

```
/// <summary>
/// My view model class
/// </summary>
public class MyVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // VM logic
    // ...

    // events
    private event EventHandler<string> OnRequestShowDialog;

    // calling event
    public void BusinessMethod()
    {
        // ...
        OnRequestShowDialog?.Invoke(this, "Business method completed successfully...");
    }}

/// <summary>
/// My page class
/// </summary>
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        // New VM 
        BindingContextChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Connect to your VM's events here
            (this.BindingContext as MyVM).OnRequestShowDialog += (e, message) => {
            this.DisplayAlert("info", args, "ok");
        };
    };
}
}
```

Hope it give you some ideas...

Answer (score 2):

The question you are asking is very common in MVVM world which turn it into opinionated topic. Some developers believe that you should navigate between your Pages / Views - V first, other believe that you should navigate between your ViewModels - VM first. Both have their own advantages and disadvantages and there are a lot of resources on the WWW about it.

I would recommend to get familiar with these 2 different approaches and then decide which one to use. You can check existing MVVM frameworks to see how they solved this problem. Luckily this topic is very interesting, so you should enjoy the investigation journey.

Most probably there will be no silver bullet that will fit different types of projects. Just keep that in mind.

Good luck!